# Documentation draft fails to retract

Tags: bug, documentation

I have a draft here that fails to retract with a "Something went wrong" error: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/video/drafts/76468/

The draft was retracted and re-submitted several times during editing. At one point, the error started to appear whenever I try to retract. If I ignore the error and "edit" the draft, I get another error on re-submission (which fails).

I have recycled the content of the draft elsewhere and just want to retract it and make it die, to clean the garbage so to speak.